# arranging definitions

Tags: python, oop, function

in python there is way to declare `def`'s without putting it in class. So, if i just need to store many `def`'s in separated class, i should simple do this:

```
def first_method():
    pass

def second_method():
    pass
```

and not use `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod`?:

```
class methods():

    @classmethod
    def first_method(cls):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def second_method():
        pass
```

if first way is right, how should i mark private and public method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just keep functions that are not instance methods out of your classes.

You're thinking like you would in Java. Python isn't Java. Python has no true way to have public and private methods -- you can change the names to indicate that you'd like some form of privacy (`_` or `__` at the beginning of the name), but it's not enforceable.

I've found that in all the time I've programmed in Python, I never wished for access modifiers.

Comment: Good answer, just one complaint: Leading `__` (name mangling) is at best useless and at worst harmful (obscure NameErrors).

Comment: @delnan didn't know that. To be honest, I've never used it (why would I?)

Comment: @delnan: could you please elaborate a bit more on that? In other words, what is it that could go wrong with name mangling? Thanks.

Comment: @sm: See http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers for the facts (Summary: Inside `class Ham`, any occurence of the identifier `__spam` gets replaced by `_Ham__spam`). Often, this won't matter because you generally don't need to access private members. But when you need to, for a perfectly valid reason (those do exist!), you'll have to hardcode the class name *and* this will disallow child classes to override those variables (as the final name is tied to the base class' name)!

Comment: Name mangling exists precisely so that a child class can use the same name without clashing. So it's not entirely useless, but there aren't many good reasons to use it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as private and public methods in Python. By convention, names that begin with a single underscore are considered "private", in a sense that user should not rely on their existence. Furthermore, you could *document* public interface. All the rest should of no relevance.

The set of mildly-related function would be a more pythonic solution, I'd say.